# CSS Calc with TOP attribute does not work

Tags: html, css

I know CSS calc works for an example like:

```
width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

But it doesn't seem to work with the "top" attribute, like:

```
top: calc(50% + 100px);
```

The object is stuck near the top of the page.

My full CSS is:

```
#tab_position_1 {
    width: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    background: #999999;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    right:0;
    top: calc(50% + 100px);
    z-index: 4;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

I have a cluster of 4 tabs that I would like to space on the edge of the page at 50% +100px, +200px, -100px, -200px, so that as the screen size changes, the cluster stays centered.  I know I can do this through javascript, but would like to know if I can do this through CSS and Calc?

Is there a way this can be done with CSS/Calc for the TOP attribute?

Comment: You have an extra % character that shouldn't be there it looks like.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I removed that extra % - still does not work.

Comment: Maybe changing position: fixed to absolute will allow it to work. It seems to work in this example: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_top

Comment: Fixed, Absolute - no change.  The link does not show Calc examples - just a pixel position, which I know works fine.

Comment: Try adjusting the top: to use calc(40% + 50px) for example

Comment: Not sure what happened, but after it is working now as expected!  Code works fine.  Something must have interfered with it in other parts of my code that maybe got corrected along the way... too hard to know exactly what occurred...

Comment: @hder, may be the div container dont have height ? i also have the same problem, and once i set the div container's height, it works ...

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code to achieve your need

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Position</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #tab_position_1 {
            width: 20px;
            height: 100px;
            position: fixed;
            background: #999999;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: white;
            right:0;
            top: calc(50% + 100px);
            z-index: 4;
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        }
        #tab_position_2 {
            width: 20px;
            height: 100px;
            position: fixed;
            background: #999999;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: white;
            right:0;
            top: calc(50% + 200px);
            z-index: 4;
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        }
        #tab_position_3 {
            width: 20px;
            height: 100px;
            position: fixed;
            background: #999999;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: white;
            right:0;
            top: calc(50% - 100px);
            z-index: 4;
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        }
        #tab_position_4 {
            width: 20px;
            height: 100px;
            position: fixed;
            background: #999999;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: white;
            right:0;
            top: calc(50% - 200px);
            z-index: 4;
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tab_position_1"></div>
<div id="tab_position_2"></div>
<div id="tab_position_3"></div>
<div id="tab_position_4"></div>
</body>
</html>
```